# Pulling Intercept from tidy functionality

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

Is it possible to pull the intercept and slope from the tidy functionality within the broom package? I know it's possible to pull r.squared from glance.

```
df <- tibble(education = c("Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High", "High"),
             wellbeing = c(7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5))
df$education <- as.factor(df$education)

mdl <- lm(
  wellbeing ~ education, 
  data = df,
  family = gaussian
)

# Pulling r.squared from glance
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
mdl %>%
  glance() %>%
  pull(r.squared)

# Pulling intercept from tidy?
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
mdl %>%
  tidy() %>%
  pull(Intercept)
```

Comment: do you mean `plot(mdl)
mdl %>% tidy() %>% pull(estimate)`. Then add `%>% 
  .[1]`

Comment: `… %>% filter(term == '(Intercept)')`? Or, if you want the values in a single column: `… %>% filter(term = '(Intercept)') %>% select(-term) %>% pivot_longer(everything())`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

We can also use `coef` function to extract the coefficients. I would like to thank Mr. @Konrad Rudolph for this valuable hint.
You can use this if I get what you want correctly. You have to use `glm` instead of `lm` function if you would like to choose the `family` as `gaussian`.

```
mdl <- glm(
    wellbeing ~ education, 
    data = df,
    family = gaussian
)

mdl %>% 
  coef()

    (Intercept)    educationLow educationMedium 
      5.3333333       0.1666667       0.1666667 

mdl %>% 
  .[["coefficients"]]

    (Intercept)    educationLow educationMedium 
      5.3333333       0.1666667       0.1666667
```

Or maybe this one:

```
mdl %>% 
  summary() %>%
  .[["coefficients"]]

                 Estimate Std. Error  t value    Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     5.3333333  0.8975275 5.942251 0.004022519
educationLow    0.1666667  1.4191155 0.117444 0.912169166
educationMedium 0.1666667  1.4191155 0.117444 0.912169166
```